# How to add Previous and Next buttons using Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I'm trying to add Previous and Next buttons to my SPA. I'm using Vue js for the frontend and Laravel for the backend.
The issue I'm having right now is that when a User clicks on either the Prev or Next buttons once it switches the id in the URL but the new data doesn't get loaded. If you click on either button again, then they start working normally.

Here is my SearchIndex.vue component:

```
nextCandidate: async function() {
                try {
                    const itemId = this.$route.params.itemId;
                    const response = await employerService.loadCandidateProfileData(itemId);
                    this.nextRecord = response.data.next_record;

                    this.$router.push(`/employer/search/filter-by/${this.nextRecord.id}/show`);
                    this.loadCandidateProfileData();

                } catch(error) {
                    this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                }
            },

            previousCandidate: async function() {
                try {
                    const itemId = this.$route.params.itemId;
                    const response = await employerService.loadCandidateProfileData(itemId);
                    this.previousRecord = response.data.previous_record;

                    this.$router.push(`/employer/search/filter-by/${this.previousRecord.id}/show`);
                    this.loadCandidateProfileData();

                } catch(error) {
                    this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                }
            },
```

```
loadCandidateProfileData: async function() {
                try {
                    const itemId = this.$route.params.itemId;
                    const response = await employerService.loadCandidateProfileData(itemId);

                    this.candidateProfiles = response.data.candidateProfiles;
                    
                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
                }
            },
```

Here are my buttons inside SearchIndex.vue component:

```
<b-row class="mt-3 text-center mb-3">
                <b-col>
                    <button @click="previousCandidate()"
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-lg btn-dark mb-3"
                    >
                        < Prev
                    </button>
                </b-col>
                <b-col>
                    <button @click="nextCandidate()"
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-lg btn-dark mb-3"
                            >
                        Next >
                    </button>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
```

So if it's showing User with id 1 in the URL and you click next, in the URL it goes to 2, but the Profile Data on the page doesn't refresh. Then if you press it again it works as normal, the data on the page refreshes and same with the Previous button. It's just the first time you press on either button.

Comment: watch the param: `watch: {'$route.params.itemId': ...}` then re-fire the loadCandidateProfileData method, instead of calling it in previousCandidate etc

Comment: also the difference between `nextCandidate` and `previousCandidate` is `previous_record/previous_record` property, so you might as well pass that though, so calling next twice/three/four times then clicking back makes sense as it doesn't track properly

Comment: In your first comment: Where do you want me to refire the loadCandidateProfileData method? Sorry I'm new to Vue js.
Second comment:
Pass it through where? Can you send me js fiddle example?

Comment: if you create a js fiddle ill be glad to tweak it :) as said in the watch `watch: {'$route.params.itemId': function (){this.loadCandidateProfileData()}}`, then you dont need the this.loadCandidateProfileData(); in the other methods.

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: Just a heads up, computed properties are preferred to watchers: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: a little example https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-driscoll-zgux1?file=/src/pages/index.vue

Comment: Thank you. I want to add a v-if to my buttons, that greys them out if the Prev button is on the first record in the db and the Next button is on the last record in the db. Because right now when it's showing the last Candidate Profile's Data in the db and you click next, I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

Comment: you could prob look at `response.data` if its null, and is no `this.previousRecord.id` from the result add a flag to disable the button, same with next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Lawrence Cherone for your comment:

```
watch: {'$route.params.itemId': function (){this.loadCandidateProfileData()}}
```

then you dont need the this.loadCandidateProfileData(); in the other methods.

NOTE: computed properties are preferred to watchers as mentioned by Adam Zerner.
But for now this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `loadCandidateProfileData` is `this.$route.params.itemId` what you expect it to be? If not, it seems like it means there's a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where `this.loadCandidateProfileData` is called before `this.$router.push` finishes.

Reading through the [router.push docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) it seems like the issue might stem from you trying to navigate to the current route, and that you'd need to use `beforeRouteUpdate`:

> Note: If the destination is the same as the current route and only
> params are changing (e.g. going from one profile to another /users/1
> -> /users/2), you will have to use beforeRouteUpdate to react to changes (e.g. fetching the user information).

It'd probably be a good idea anyway to pass the id into `loadCandidateProfileData` though rather than looking at `this.$route.params.itemId` from inside `loadCandidateProfileData`. Doing so might fix your problem.

Comment: Yes this.$route.params.itemId is what I expect it to be. Sorry I'm new to Vue js. What do you mean by pass it through, pass it through what exactly?

Comment: I mean to pass the id into the function as an argument rather than accessing the id via global state from within the function.